# No preview/edit buttons in SmartEdit

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront, smartedit

We are creating a Spartacus storefront for buyer/seller users. Our users asked if they could use SmartEdit to update our rotating banner component for their promotions. The problem is that I can't see the edit even the preview button. Our Hybris version is 2211. I can't find any references to fix this.
[image]

**EDIT**: I checked this link, https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/smartEdit-setup-instructions-for-spartacus/#the-perspective-toolbar-is-missing, and as you can see in my screenshot below, I have here webApplicationInjector.js.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who sees this post, you can check here, https://answers.sap.com/questions/12885483/smart-edit-error-when-open-pages.html. I followed the steps and managed to make it work.